# Чтение и анализ постоянно изменяющегося файла javafx

Tags: java

Здравствуйте подскажите как можно реализовать прослушивание текстового файла, который постоянно изменятся.

Текстовый файл состоит из следующих букв: `H H H H A A D A`. То есть всего три разных символа. Символы разделены пробелами. Необходимо при изменении файла, запустить процедуру анализа файла.

При интеграции watch service, gui перестала запускать, работает только watch service.Как совместить watch service с gui.Ошибку никакую не выдает.Код написан внизу

```
public class ReadFromFile {
    public void readFromFile() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        final Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
        System.out.println(path);
        try (final WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
            final WatchKey watchKey = path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
            while (true) {
                final WatchKey wk = watchService.take();
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents()) {
                    //we only register "ENTRY_MODIFY" so the context is always a Path.
                    final Path changed = (Path) event.context();
                    System.out.println(changed);
                    if (changed.endsWith("football.txt")) {
                        System.out.println("My file has changed");
                    }
                }
                // reset the key
                boolean valid = wk.reset();
                if (!valid) {
                    System.out.println("Key has been unregisterede");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
void initialize() throws Exception {
    ReadFromFile rf = new ReadFromFile();
    rf.readFromFile();

}
```

Comment: Первая же ссылка в гугле [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: Только как это можно совместить с javafx,если запускаю watchservice, gui не запускается

Comment: Показывай код. WatchService никак не мешает использовать GUI

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/52GbN3tuUtAtVg            Ссылка на проект

Comment: Так не пойдет. Выкладывай код сюда (не весь проект, а кусок с вотчером). Никто не будет качать твои архивы. Почитай [эту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) статью и оформи тему.

Comment: класс контроллер
ReadFromFile rf = new ReadFromFile();
    rf.readFromFile();

класс watchService

final Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath
 try (final WatchService watchService = FileS
final WatchKey watchKey = path.re
 while (true) {
                final WatchKey wk = watchService.take();
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents()) {
                    
                    final Path changed = (Path) event.context();
 

   boolean valid = wk.reset();
                if (!valid) {

Comment: Во первых это не читабельно, во вторых обрезалось. Отредактируй сам вопрос и вставь туда код оформив его в markdown.